# Group rows on some colums and use SUM

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, axapta, ssrs-2008-r2, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a table defined in AX like follows:

[image]

I am trying to create an SSRS report using a query to create the DataSet and as Design - PrecisionDesign.

I got this until now:

[image]

with groupings :

[image]

I would like to visually replicate this query:

```
SELECT Country
    , City
    , FirstName
    , SUM(AGE)
FROM TABLESSRSGROUPING
GROUP BY Country, City, FirstName
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need to group once within the first Row Grouping.

In the Group Properties - group on [Country] then ADD [City] then ADD [Name]

Let me know if this helps[image]

Comment: I must admit i did the same thing 2 mins ago and it worked. I was not sure about this approach but seeing your response made me feel like i am not doing smth completely wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What value do you have in the sum field in the SSRS report?
Is it

Fields!.Age.Value

or

sum(Fields!.Age.Value)

Comment: =SUM(Fields!Age.Value)

Answer (score 1):

Your report is diplaying the DETAIL for all records.

The **Details** group has the three lines to the left, indicating that it is **showing all lines** and **NOT grouping** like you want.

Change your Details to Group on **FirstName** and delete your **FirstName** group (select **DELETE GROUP ONLY** not the Related Rows and Columns)

On a different note, you're adding AGEs?